# Passport.js server Auto Login

Tags: passport.js

Passport.js presents a method req.login, req is request to server.

Is it possible to implement AutoLogin on server side without making request from client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean without the user making explicit login if he has been authenticated earlier. Given that you have added the passport middleware in the express setup:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

it will check if the client already has the `passport` cookie and redirect him automatically to wherever he would normally go on successful authentication.